# Javascript (Angular Js) exporting Json as excel (with letters in fonts)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement to Json to Excel exporting in javascript. I am using angular js. I was to able to generate Json to CSV but i cant not retain font(bold) and macros in CSV (because its csv). 
Is there any opensource in the market for Json to Excel  conversion by retaining font colours for the text.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting project on github called **Excel Builder (.js)**
that offers a client-side way of downloading Excel **xlsx** files and includes options for formatting the Excel spreadsheet.
https://github.com/stephenliberty/excel-builder.js

You may encounter both browser and Excel compatibility issues using this library, but under the right conditions, it may be quite useful.

The demos on github project with less Excel options but less worries about Excel compatibility issues can be found here: **ExcellentExport.js**
https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport

The demos seem to hold some promise.
http://excelbuilderjs.com/index.html

If you are using AngularJS, there is **[ng-csv](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-csv)**:
a "Simple directive that turns arrays and objects into downloadable CSV files".